# MVC Margin/Rounded edges on image

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.2

Let me start by saying I'm new to this development, MVC and so forgive anything I might misname but I will do my best.

**A Little Background**: A web designed created my front end all in HTML, with CSS and used bootstrap and some JS.  I have created a default MVC 5 project with a login and even successfully added external login connectors.  Now I'm trying to get his design into my project and so far its worked really well.

**Issues**
 1. On my index page the image at the top which stretches across the top under the nav bar has rounded corners.  On the other pages they have the same image but its smaller and is referenced in a similar manner but with a -sub on it and it doesn't have the rounded corners.  I've scoured the CSS files (entire solution search) and I found a couple of radius commands on them but even removing it doesn't change the image.  I'm not sure where its inheriting it.

in my **custom.css** file here is the reference the -sub version doesn't have rounded corners)

```
.jumbotron { background-color: #c9e9f2; background: url("/images/Hero-1.png") no-repeat center center #c9e9f2; height: 480px; width: 100%; text-align:center; }
.jumbotron-sub { background-color: #c9e9f2; background: url("/images/Hero-1.png") no-repeat center bottom #c9e9f2; height: 280px; text-align:center; }
```

Index Page (where its rounded, the other pages are identical with -sub behind the name).

```
<body>
<div class="jumbotron">
</div>
```

2. On all my pages there is a small margin on each side.  On the html page I took the code from it doesn't exist.  Is there a global setting adding this in?  On some pages the margin is needed (where the image doesn't exist) but on others i wont want it.

Code same as above.